# Can't Build Wheel for Python Library "pesq" - "fatal error: 'math.h': No such file or directory"

Tags: python, pip, python-wheel

I'm trying install a python library named as 'pesq'(https://pypi.org/project/pesq/). As you can see from down below I'm getting error while building wheel:

## **Error**

```
Collecting pesq
  Using cached pesq-0.0.4.tar.gz (38 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Installing backend dependencies ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: pesq
  Building wheel for pesq (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for pesq (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [29 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-38
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-38\pesq
      copying pesq\_pesq.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-38\pesq
      copying pesq\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-38\pesq
      copying pesq\cypesq.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-38\pesq
      copying pesq\dsp.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-38\pesq
      copying pesq\pesq.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-38\pesq
      copying pesq\pesqio.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-38\pesq
      copying pesq\pesqmain.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-38\pesq
      copying pesq\pesqpar.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-38\pesq
      copying pesq\dsp.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-38\pesq
      copying pesq\pesqdsp.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-38\pesq
      copying pesq\pesqmod.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-38\pesq
      running build_ext
      cythoning pesq/cypesq.pyx to pesq\cypesq.c
      building 'cypesq' extension
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-38
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-38\Release
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-38\Release\pesq
      "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Ipesq -IC:\Users\aliemir\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-l1h82fpj\normal\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -IC:\Users\aliemir\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-l1h82fpj\normal\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -IC:\Users\aliemir\anaconda3\envs\tts-fast\include -IC:\Users\aliemir\anaconda3\envs\tts-fast\Include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\include" /Tcpesq/dsp.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-38\Release\pesq/dsp.obj
      dsp.c
      pesq/dsp.c(105): fatal error C1083: i‡erme dosyas\x8d a‡\x8dlam\x8dyor: 'math.h': No such file or directory
      C:\Users\aliemir\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-l1h82fpj\normal\Lib\site-packages\Cython\Compiler\Main.py:369: FutureWarning: Cython directive 'language_level' not set, using 2 for now (Py2). This will change in a later release! File: C:\Users\aliemir\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-uwz3mea7\pesq_54c683f7e04241abbcd6048c16a56a0e\pesq\cypesq.pyx
        tree = Parsing.p_module(s, pxd, full_module_name)
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.27.29110\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pesq
Failed to build pesq
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pesq, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

## **What have I tried so far**

I've upgraded my pip, wheel and setup tools like described at this website, https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/python-pip-install-failed-building-wheel-for

I've also tried this,
`python -m pip install -U pip setuptools`

I'm using conda environment and hence I've upgraded my pip, wheel and setup tools within environment as well.

I've tried to install pesq like this, `pip install --use-pep517 pesq`

## **My thoughts**

When you look at my error block you will see that **"fatal error C1083: i‡erme dosyas\x8d a‡\x8dlam\x8dyor: 'math.h': No such file or directory"** and the **'i‡erme dosyas\x8d a‡\x8dlam\x8dyor'** part is in Turkish and basically it tries to say *"Can't find file"*.

While searching this error I come across with 'gcc' and and as you can see from 'https://pypi.org/project/pesq/', pesq need C Complier. Therefore I've installed gcc with using MinGW (I've follow steps from 'https://dev.to/gamegods3/how-to-install-gcc-in-windows-10-the-easier-way-422j') and my gcc version is 6.3.0 but it didn't work either. So, I think I've problems with 'gcc'.

Thanks for reading and support :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So.... I've just solved my problem... It was caused by the version of Visual Studio version. I've updated it from here https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/tr/visual-cpp-build-tools/ and update solved my problem.